# Material UI - Theme Style - typography not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply typography changes to the theme using Material UI. But object changes are not working. However, the palette is working.

I tried to make some changes to the H3 variation and also to the default font size, but none of the changes work.

However, the colors on the palette work.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/ui/Header";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import theme from "./components/ui/Theme";

function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Header />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Header/index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import useScrollTrigger from "@mui/material/useScrollTrigger";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

function ElevationScroll(props) {
    const { children, window } = props;
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0,
        target: window ? window() : undefined,
    });

    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 10 : 0,
    });
}

function Header() {
    return (
        <ElevationScroll>
            <AppBar color="primary">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h3" component="h3">
                        Nome de teste
                    </Typography>
                    <h3>Teste</h3>
                    Teste
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </ElevationScroll>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

**Theme.js**

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const arcBlue = "#0B72B9";
const arcOrange = "#FFBA60";

export default createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontSize: 60,
        h3: {
            fontWeight: 500,
        },
    },
    palette: {
        common: {
            blue: `${arcBlue}`,
            orange: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
        primary: {
            main: `${arcBlue}`,
        },
        secondary: {
            main: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
    },
});
```

If anyone can help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You're importing `ThemeProvider` from v4. See [this](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#mui-styles).

Comment: Got it, I was importing from:

`import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";`

However, according to the documentation, it needs to be:

`import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, it's only for v4, in v5 use `@mui/material/styles`. MUI v4 and v5 uses different style libraries so v4 `ThemeProvider` wouldn't work with v5 styling API.

Comment: The documentation seems to be quite confusing on this issue. But I made the change as you informed, and it worked. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 9):

**Solution**

I was importing from:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
```

However, according to the documentation, it needs to be:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
```