# Material UI - makeStyles - Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm studying Material UI, and in the course, the instructor asks me to style just one component and not the entire theme.

For that, it uses the **`makeStyles`** function and spreads the `theme.mixins.toolbar`. The problem is when I do this, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toolbar')
```

This course is apparently in version 4, and I am using version 5. Despite this, my code appears to follow the changes that the documentations asks for. So what could be causing this error?

**app.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/ui/Header";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "./components/ui/Theme";

function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Header />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Theme.js**

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const arcBlue = "#0B72B9";
const arcOrange = "#FFBA60";

export default createTheme({
    typography: {
        h3: {
            fontWeight: 100,
        },
    },
    palette: {
        common: {
            blue: `${arcBlue}`,
            orange: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
        primary: {
            main: `${arcBlue}`,
        },
        secondary: {
            main: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
    },
});
```

**header/index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import useScrollTrigger from "@mui/material/useScrollTrigger";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

function ElevationScroll(props) {
    const { children, window } = props;
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0,
        target: window ? window() : undefined,
    });

    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 10 : 0,
    });
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    toolbarMargin: { ...theme.mixins.toolbar },
}));

function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ElevationScroll>
                <AppBar color="primary">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h3" component="h3">
                            Nome de teste
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </ElevationScroll>
            <div className={classes.toolBarMargin} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Didn't you just [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69546538/9449426) yourself recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using v5, change your `ThemeProvider`, `createTheme` and `makeStyles` import path from:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

To:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
```

`@material-ui/core` is v4 package and `@mui/material` is the v5 equivalent. The API from the 2 versions are not compatible. In v5, `makeStyles` is also moved to a legacy package called `@mui/styles`, if you are using MUI v5 in a new project, you should switch completely to `styled`/`sx` API as [recommended](https://mui.com/styles/basics/#main-content) by the MUI team.

### Related answers

- [Difference between @mui/material/styles and @mui/styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69506133/9449426)
- [Cannot use palette colors from MUI theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69399031/9449426)
- [MUI createTheme is not properly passing theme to MUI components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69419447/9449426)

Comment: In addition to the changes mentioned, I needed to make three more things to work.
```npm install @mui/styles```, then ```import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";````, and I also called the object classes using the correct propety, with b in lowercase.

From: ```<div className={classes.toolBarMargin} />``` to ```<div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />```

Comment: @MaximilianKaden If you're creating a new project. You should drop `makeStyles` usage and switch to `styled`/`sx` instead. It's the recommended API in v5 whereas `makeStyles` is a legacy one and might be remove in future verions of MUI.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue with `Can not read properties of undefined, reading refs` thrown by `makeStyles`. In my case it was mui v5 and the issue occurred after upgrading to React 18.

In my case it turned out I had some legacy `makeStyles(()=>createStyles)` wrapped in a manner:

```
const useStyles = (minWidth: number) =>
  makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ...
```

I had to change it to:

```
const useStyles =
  makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ...
```

Perhaps it will be useful for somebody else facing the issue.

Comment: Hey @jckmlczk 
I am facing exactly same issue after upgrading to React 18 but I am already having the makeStyles in specified way:

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    minWidth: '100px',
  },
}));

Comment: From what I checked it turns out everywhere I am using it with createStyles: import createStyles from "@mui/styles/createStyles"; import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles"; const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({ root: { flexGrow: 1, minWidth: '100px', }, })); - maybe try this approach? If I remember correctly createStyles is a type wrapper for style object.

Comment: I got above error in a component where `makeStyles` was called directly as `const classes = makeStyles(...)()`...

Answer (score 2):

I created a project on CodeSandbox and it doesn't seem the problem in code.
I guess you need to check the version of package you installed in `package.json` file.

Here is the link to the CodeSandbox  project and you can see the console.log message on console tab.

https://codesandbox.io/s/check-makestyle-eq67m?file=/src/components/ui/Header/index.js

Comment: Hi @jihyun lee. Using version 4 of Material UI actually works. Your example code uses the ```"@material-ui/core" version: "4.12.3"```. But the updated version (That I'm using), is ```"@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5"```.

Comment: Opps. My bad. should've checked the version. Like the NearHuscarl's answer, you need to change the module name from `@material-ui/core/styles` to `@mui/material/styles`. I changed the the example code and it works!

Comment: Yeah, also need to import { makeStyles } from ```"@mui/styles";``` instead of ```@material-ui/styles;```. This is not noted in the new documentation by the way. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Install @mui/styles

`npm install @mui/styles`

Change

`import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";`

To

`import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";`

And

`import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";`

To

`import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";`

And

`<div className={classes.toolBarMargin} />`

To

`<div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />`